# How to make vnc server and ldap authentication work together?

Tags: vnc, openldap

I have a RHEL 6.4 box and I am running `tigervnc-server` on the box to enable remote gui access for different users. I have the users created locally and have created separate displays for them in the `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers` file, as well as `vncpasswds` in their home directories.

Now I'm thinking about moving the users to OpenLDAP and configuring `sshd` to authenticate via LDAP with the user home directories moved to a common NFS share. So with LDAP authentication in place, am I supposed to separately create displays and `vncpasswd` in the home directory for every new user added to the LDAP database?

Is there some way to automatically create a display for a new user who logs in and have the vncserver authenticate against the LDAP directory ? Do I need a different VNC server?

Comment: This is for RealVNC, but it should get you started [Managing system authentication](http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.1/guides/user/am1082517.html)

Comment: I'm also too new in here, so I cannot post comments. @ Creek - you suggested RealVNC documentation. That's nice, but RealVNC isn't OpenSource. The asker was asking about TigerVNC - this documentation doesn't help... @ Michael McGarrah - What's your conclusions from your research of Guacamole? I've also started checking it, but it seems problematic for me that the user can use only hard-coded pre-defined VNC sessions. When using TigerVNC directly, the user can open as many VNC sessions as needed, with arbitrary display geometries, and they can be easily shared with other users.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be completely off topic but have you considered the Guacamole web application? It offers a web frontend and authentication to VNC and RDP clients. I'm researching it right now as part of removing a legacy ssl vpn service. Guacamole has LDAP support.

Sorry, I had to post this as an answer. To new to this section to comment.